# What is the probability of selecting 4 spades from a deck of 52 cards if each card is replaced before the next one is selected?

Tags: probability, statistics

So there are in total 13 spades, The probability of choosing one would be $$1/13$$ so do i multiply it 4 times together? even if i do that I still won't get the correct answer. and also it says replaced so the numbers can't go down each time right? how would I solve this?

Comment: One quarter are spades.  Your basic idea is right, the probability is $(1/4)^4$.

Answer (score 4):

So the probability of getting a spade on the first draw is $\frac{13}{52}$ since there are $13$ spades in a standard deck of $52$ cards. But this is the same each time since you draw with replacement. Therefore, since each event is independent, you can multiply the probabilities:
$$P(S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4) = P(S_1)P(S_2)P(S_3)P(S_4) = \left(\frac{13}{52}\right)^4,$$
where $S_i = \text{Spade on draw $i$}$, for $i = 1,2,3,4$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a typical 'AND' problem where you multiply probabilities. You need to get a Spade AND another AND another AND another with replacement. So,

$\frac{13}{52} \ * \frac{13}{52} * \frac{13}{52} * \frac{13}{52}$